# Создание функции с привязкой к любой кнопке

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Можно ли в xcode на swift сделать функцию без привязки к определённому view controller , но с возможностью привязывать к **ЛЮБОЙ** кнопке , если что то при нажатии на кнопку исполняется функция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать создать extension для ViewController с нужным методом. Может получится привязать. Другой вариант - сделать для нужных ViewController-ов свой базовый класс и от него наследоваться.

Пример с расширением:

```
extension UIViewController {
    @IBAction func actionButton() {

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете завернуть статическую функцию в класс, так как глобальные функции не могут быть `@objc`:

```
class TestClass {
    @objc static func testFunction() {
        print("testFunction")
    }
}

// MARK: - Назначаете:

yourButton.addTarget(TestClass.self, action: #selector(TestClass.testFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Либо создать кастомную кнопку и сделать в ней:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        print("Test")
    }
}
```